# How to get access to UITableViewController properties when subclassing from UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I have subclassed UIViewController to provide common functionality for all UIViewControllers (for example I'm overriding viewDidLoad method). My app uses a bunch of view controllers that are arranged inside tab bar controller and in navigation controllers. Everything is OK, except the fact I have one UITableViewController. I would like to subclass not it but my custom MyUIViewController. I'm able to get the table working by implementing data source and delegate protocols:

```
@interface MaschinenTableViewController : MyUIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

However in this case, I do not have an access to UITableViewController properties. For example, I cannot change the behavior of table row selection because self is MyUIViewController not UITableViewController:

```
self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = YES;
```

Are there any workarounds for accessing those properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you will need to add a UITableView variable to the header and set it up appropriately in viewDidLoad, and add it to your view. From this point it will work as a UITableViewController will (as essentially that's all it does!)

Take a look [at my article here which takes this approach.](http://www.locassa.com/index.php/2011/05/animate-uitableview-cell-height-change/)

Comment: Thanks but clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear property is not found in UITableView. I did what you have suggested but I'm unable to use    self.tableView.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear.

Comment: You can clear the table manually in viewWillAppear if that is the behaviour you want.

Comment: Ok, what method should I use?

Comment: Implement the delegate method - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath and store the indexPath as an instance variable (put it in the header), then on viewWillAppear call - (void)deselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath animated:(BOOL)animated on the table and pass in the indexPath, THEN set the indexPath to nil.

Comment: On viewWillAppear you should check if your indexPath is nil and only deselect when it isn't.

Comment: Thanks. I have wired myTableView in IB and I placed the code [self.myTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.myTableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:animated], but indexPath always returns 0.

Comment: At last found what was causing a problem. In my IB, I have wired the tableView outlet with file owner view property because my xib contained only the tableView. But even after casting "UITableView castedTableView* = (UITableView *) self.view" the object was not respoding to deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated: because castedTableView was nil. Everything worked after putting the view in IB, wiring it with file owner view and wiring the tableView  with tableView outlet.

Comment: Hm... thought if UITableView inherits from UIScrollView and UIView then it should be OK to wire my tableView directly to the file owner view, thought the view is redundant in IB.

Answer (score 1):

You could also subclass UITableViewController as MyUITableViewController, implementing the behavior you want, and then put a MyUITableViewController as variable to your MyUIViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Did the same as [Simon Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846808/how-to-get-access-to-uitableviewcontroller-properties-when-subclassing-from-uivi#comment9568928_7846922) mentioned using the delegate. 
 But without storing the index anywhere, at the end of didSelectRowAtIndexPath method called the deselectRowAtIndexPath. Worked for me no issues so far.